# namespaceing for service class in symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, autoload

I am facing one problem I do not know what is a reason of this I add class with location in my project src/ApiMaps/ApiMapBundle  with this name space

```
   <?php
     namespace ApiMaps\ApiMapService;

  class ApiMapService {
  private $transport;
   public function __construct() {
    $this->transport = 'sendmail';
  }
// ...
}
```

when i give in

```
       src/config/service.yml

      app.test:  
      class:  ApiMaps\ApiMapService\ApiMapService
      arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

and when i run it from some other class for example

```
 src/ApiMaps/ApiMapBundle/Command/GetApiCommand.php


 class GetApiCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
   {  
   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
     {
   $number = $this->getContainer()->get('app.test');
     }
   }
```

it give me error

Fatal error: Class 'ApiMaps\ApiMapService\ApiMapService' not found in   D:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectMapApiData\a
pp\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 325
[2016-02-01 08:25:20] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Class 'ApiMaps\ApiMapService\ApiMapService' not found {"
type":1,"file":"D:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectMapApiData\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","
line":325,"level":-1,"stack":[]}

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]
  Attempted to load class "ApiMapService" from namespace "ApiMaps\ApiMapService".
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Note--
one thing to mention that when i try to make service from the built-in class   of symfony2 classes it does not give me such error. I do know where I need to add the namespace of the class which i recently added with my project that it able to know the class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that your service in file:
`src/ApiMaps/ApiMapBundle`

but in config you wrote:
`ApiMaps\ApiMapService\ApiMapService`.

I think you should house you service in file: `src/ApiMaps/ApiMapBundle/ApiMapService/ApiMapService.php`,

take namespace: `ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService`

and write in config: `ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService\ApiMapService`.

Truly believe it'll help you...

Comment: now i added this namespace with my class which is inside in src/ApiMaps/ApiMapBundle/ApiMapService.php        namespace ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService;     and in config/sercvice.yml when i call it with      app.test:  
         class:   ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService
         arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]   now it give me error

Comment: [RuntimeException]
  The autoloader expected class "ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService" to be defined in file "D:\xampp\h
 tdocs\ProjectMapApiData/src\ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService.php". The file was found but the clas
  s was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService\ApiMapService' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\Projec
tMapApiData\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 325
[2016-02-01 08:51:04] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Class 'ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService\ApiMapService'
 not found "type":1,"file":"D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ProjectMapApiData\\app\\ cache\\dev\\appDevDebugProjectCon
tainer.php","line":325,"level":-1,"stack":[]}

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]
  Attempted to load class "ApiMapService" from namespace "ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService".
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: thankx for your response. This error i am getting now when i change it according to your suggestion.

Comment: try namespace `ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService` and config `ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService\ApiMapService`.

Comment: [RuntimeException]
  Case mismatch between class and real file names: ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService\ApiMapService.ph
  p vs ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\APiMapService\ApiMapService.php in D:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectMapApiData\src\



cron:getapi [--yell] [--] [<name>]

Comment: app.test:  
         class:   ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService\ApiMapService
         arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]                                            and namespace is  namespace ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\ApiMapService;   file location is right now src/ApiMaps/ApiMapBundle/ApiMapService/ApiMapService.php

Comment: awesome!) i'm glad!)